# Dynamics CRM: Bulk update triggered automatically without actually having done so

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I found out today that there has been a bulk update for contact and account entity for the owner field. We did not trigger a workflow nor did we do any operation with regard to an update.

Audit Log shows that one sales rep has changed the owner field for about 850 contacts but the sales rep has not manually triggered any workflow nor updated any record.

All these 850+ records have the same update time.

I have no idea what has happened or why.

Comment: the modifiedby of these records is perhaps SYSTEM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your sales rep opened the user record of the previous owner of these 850+ contacts and clicked on `Reassign Records` instead of changing only the value for the single lookup.

In this way the records are reassigned and the `modifiedby` is `SYSTEM`

[image]

Note: happened to a customer in a CRM Online environment

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now! Is there a remedy for this?

Comment: You can use advanced find to find the records and assign back to the original user 250 records at time.